# How to reverse transform request from json api to proper data using Laravel, Lumen, Dingo, Ember Data?

Tags: laravel, ember.js, ember-data, lumen, dingo-api

I am using Lumen + Dingo + Ember JS
I am able to transform the response into JSON API. But when I post back the data from Ember, is it in same json api format. So I want to know is there any way to deform the json api data ?

data":{"attributes":{"size":2},"relationships":{"page":{"data":{"type":"pages","id":"2"}}},"type":"rows"}}

From above response, i want to get `size=2, pageId=2

I have properly used relationship in Lumen models.

Any idea, how can I achieve this?

P.s The question is about deformation of data from json api format, but not about json encode/decode.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to decode in javascript then

```
JSON.parse(jsonString) // where jsonString is your string this will return parsed object in javascript
```

if you are trying to decode in php then

```
json_decode(jsonString) // will give you stdClass object
```

Comment: :Its not about json encode decode. The question is about deformation of data from json api format.

Comment: Yes, Gaurav is right. The question is about deformation of data from json api format.

Comment: if the above data is in string format than json_decode() in php will deform it to object or array whichever you want check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php